# Sometimes IoException:Mark Invalid Jsoup Android App

Tags: java, android, exception, jsoup

I have a little problem with my code/program. 
So let me first explain what it should do.
When I press a button then it connects via Jsoup on a Website from a partner of us, thats the reason I can't post the link here, and get from the site informations about free parking spaces. After that it changes the text fields color to red if the parking space is used.

I get this Error sometimes.

W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Mark invalid

and it marks the .get(); in final Document doc

The weird thing for me is sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't and I get the exception I don't have a idea what to do now.

Here is my code

```
Thread connection= new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
        String URL = "URL";

        Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(URL)
                .data("loginTextField", "login", "pwdTextField", "password")
                .method(Method.POST)
                .execute();

        String cookieID = res.cookie("PHPSESSID");

        final Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL)
                .cookie("PHPSESSID", cookieID)
                .get();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                String doc1 = doc.outerHtml();

                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(doc1);
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();


                    if (line.contains("Status : full") {
                        park1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                        park1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    }

                }
                scanner.close();

            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Use latest Jsoup version. It's fixed now.

---

It's a known issue, already reported as a bug in Jsoup: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/1218

As a workaround you can write it a bit differently so instead of

```
final Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL)
     .cookie("PHPSESSID", cookieID)
     .get();
```

you should try

```
Response response = Jsoup.connect(URL)
     .cookie("PHPSESSID", cookieID)
     .execute();
final Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response.body());
```

Comment: Ty Krystian G it worked, i was having this problem for weeks and tried to solve it and didnt expect that that was a bug from Jsoup. I tested it with an infinite while loop for several minutes and no Exceptions. Ty again